# Azure Expressroute for O365 and IaaS

Tags: azure, office365, azure-virtual-network, iaas

Is it okay to use a single Azure Expressroute connection for both Office 365 and Cloud Infrastructure migration? My customer is moving towards O365, and later probably next year they will start moving their infrastructure assets including their developer workstations to Azure IaaS. Customer is concerned about the public internet based communication and wants to implement a secure and faster communication channel. However, I understand that just for O365 Expressroute maybe an overkill, but considering the longer term plans, I can safely suggest Expressroute. So, my questions are:

1. A single Expressoute connection can handle both O365 and Cloud
   Infra migration?
2. Is there a difference in the type of circuits used for O365 and
   Cloud Infra?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would think that you can easily accomplish that depending, on how much bandwidth you are piping through the ExpressRoute
2. ExpressRoute for Azure and for Office365, all run off the same hardware / circuits as far as i can recall.

*Great diagram for Azure ExpressRoute for O365:*
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/azure-expressroute-for-office-365-6d2534a2-c19c-4a99-be5e-33a0cee5d3bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

**Important to note**:

> Some connections such as Public DNS and Content Delivery Network nodes
>   still require the public internet connection. Also the
>   users who are not located in their ExpressRoute connected
>   building are connecting over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

1) For sure you could use a single ExpressRoute circuit. Circuits are available with speeds from 50 Mb to 10 Gb- speeds and prices: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/expressroute/.

2) Initially, i would suggest just signing up for Microsoft peering. This will allow you to configure Route Filters with the BGP Communities relevant to Office 365 and your use case- like Exchange Online (to move mailboxes). If you work with your Microsoft account manager/TAM to get approval for Azure AD as well, you can move authentication via the BGP Community "Other Office 365 Services".

I would stress though that Office 365 is designed to work over the public internet. Most customers i've worked with in the past migrated 100's of Gb's worth of mail over the public internet with no issue at all, averaging 5-10 Gb data of uploads per hour on 100 Mb WAN links contended with general internet traffic.